# nodemailer is not sending emails if the website is not running

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, nodemailer

I'm using **nodemailer** on my MERN website to send a reminder email based on a date. It's working fine when the website is running in the browser, otherwise, it's not sending emails even if the date match!

**nodemailer config:**

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

module.exports.sendEmail = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: //service,
    host: //host,
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: //email,
      pass: //pass,
    },
  });

  transporter.verify((err, success) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log("Your config is correct: ");
  });


// mapping through the database to grab the needed data based on the date 

    const mailOptions = {
      from: //email,
      to: //email2,
      subject: "You should recied an email",
      text: `This is a test email!`,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, async (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
      }
      transporter.close();
    });

//end of mapping

  next();
});
```

**server.js :**

```
...
const { sendEmail } = require("./...sendEmail path");
...
app.use(sendEmail);
...
```

I'm not able to figure out where is the issue and how to fix it, so I will be thankful If anyone can help!

Comment: You need to use one of job scheduling third party package. You may use one of following popular library  [Node Schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), [Node Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron), [Agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda), etc.

Comment: @ArifKhan Thanks!! I used **Node Corn** and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue with **node-cron** job scheduling package.

**server.js:**

```
...
const cron = require("node-cron");
const { sendEmail } = require("./...sendEmail path");
...
//app.use(sendEmail); //no need anymore

cron.schedule("*/5 * * * *", () => {
  sendEmail();
  console.log("running a task every five minutes");
});
...
```

but I had to remove `next()` from my **sendEmail** middleware

---

If you want to read more about node-cron [Click Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)